# Unable to Setup Module Federation in Nextjs 12 using webpack 5 | I cannot use @module-fedration/next-mf plugin due to org storage constraint

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webpack-5

I want to use my server app component into my shop app component

my server app next config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const packageJson = require("./package.json");

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { isServer } = options;

    config.experiments = { outputModule: false };
    config.optimization = {
      runtimeChunk: false,
    };

    config.plugins.push(
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "server",
        filename: `static/${isServer ? "ssr" : "chunks"}/remoteEntry.js`,
        exposes: {
          "./Footer": "./components/Footer",
          "./Nav": "./components/Nav",
        },
        shared: {
          react: {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: packageJson.dependencies.react,
            eager: true,
          },
          "react-dom": {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: packageJson.dependencies["react-dom"],
            eager: true,
          },
        },

      })
    );
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

my shop app next config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const packageJson = require("./package.json");

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    const { isServer } = options;

    config.experiments = { outputModule: false };
    config.optimization = {
      runtimeChunk: false,
    };

    config.plugins.push(
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "shopApp",
        remotes: {
          server: `server@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/${
            isServer ? "ssr" : "chunks"
          }/remoteEntry.js`,
        },
        shared: {
          react: {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: packageJson.dependencies.react,
            eager: true,
          },
          "react-dom": {
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: packageJson.dependencies["react-dom"],
            eager: true,
          },
        },
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I am importing my Nav and Header in my pages/index.tsx as

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import Header from "../components/Header";

const Nav = dynamic(
  () => import("pranaamUI/Nav").then((mod) => ({ default: mod.Nav })),
  { ssr: false }
) as React.ComponentType;

const Footer = dynamic(
  () => import("pranaamUI/Footer").then((mod) => ({ default: mod.Footer })),
  { ssr: false }
) as React.ComponentType;

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Nav>
        <>Shop Nav</>
      </Nav>
      <main className={styles.main}>Shop App</main>
      <Footer>
        <>Footer of Shop</>
      </Footer>
    </>
  );
}
```

as per observation my server app is successfully export remoteEntry.js and shop is also call it but

i am unable to solve below error

I am getting the error attached screenshot

I want to import the exported modules from my server app to my shop app

I have read many articles but unable to fit in my case

As already said I cannot use @module-federation/next-mf npm package because of organization memory constraint.